# c# Office Interop Slow When Looping through each word in a large document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I have the following code segment which loops through each word in a Word document, finds lines (sentences) which are bolded and stores them in a list, `MasterSentences`.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = new Document();
object path = fileDialog.FileName;
object missing = Type.Missing;

doc = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
string sentence = "";
foreach (Range rng in doc.StoryRanges)
{
    foreach (Range rngWord in rng.Words)
    {
        if ((rngWord.Text.Contains("\n") || rngWord.Text.Contains("\r")) && sentence != "")
        {
            MasterSentences.Add(sentence);
            sentence = "";
        }
        else if (rngWord.Bold != 0 && rngWord.Text != " " && rngWord.Text != "\t")
        {
            sentence += rngWord.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this takes around 3-4 minutes to complete for a Word document with 23,742 words.

Is there any way to improve the speed? Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: better use OpenXML or NPOI, I have worked with 300000 records, and the performance is fantastic, with this libraries dont need to install excel :)

Comment: Consider using `Range.Find.Execute` as shown at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ce718bc0-1b68-4a9f-af61-501ce2d32ded/using-cnet-how-to-replace-bold-text-in-ms-word-2007-with-ltbgttextltbgt-?forum=worddev .

Comment: How do I go about storing the matched text in Range.Find.Execute, it seems I can only replace it once I find it?

Comment: It's difficult to give you a useful answer without understanding exactly what it is you need to do. Can you describe more accurately what you consider a "Sentence" to be? Note that Word does have a `Sentences` collection, which might be more efficient than the `Words` collection. The idea of using `Range.Find` would probably be most efficient, if your terms lend themselves to Word's built-in search capabilities - but we can't judge that without more exact information. You can manipulate a Find result. There are lots of examples of using `Range.Find` on Stack Overflow, also using C#.

Comment: To clarify my problem I am defining a sentence as a ordered collection of bolded words until the end of a line

Comment: Don't post your solution as an edit to your question: post it as a ANSWER then mark it as such. As it is, this still appears in the lists as "unanswered". That doesn't help others who may have the same problem nor those who take the time to view the Question, thinking they may be able to help. Also, if you respond to someone in comments you should "ping" them so that they see it: @JustinBraham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your feedback. It seems using Range.Find.Execute was the right way. Here's my updated mostly working code. It takes only around 20 seconds now which is perfect.

```
Range rngFindBold = doc.Range();
rngFindBold.Find.Font.Bold = 1;
while (rngFindBold.Find.Execute(Format: true))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rngFindBold.Text))
    {
        MasterSentences.Add(rngFindBold.Text);
    }
}
```